# Would golf ball with only half hemisphere filled with dimples self correct itself?

Tags: drag, aerodynamics

Imagine a golf ball with one hemisphere covered with dimples and the other half hemisphere is smooth. Suppose I launch the same golf ball at random orientation into the air numerous time, would the dimples side always face windward so that the smooth side is always leeward?

Answer (score 0):

Always?  Almost certainly not.  This is more of an engineering problem, you would have to test to be sure.  I seriously doubt that even someone who is highly familiar with fluid dynamics could give you a concrete answer, but you could certainly make some educated guesses.  Sorry if that's not very helpful.